# Linux nat with a secondary ip address

Tags: linux, networking, router, nat

I want to setup nat on a server/router with a multiple public ip addresses (on different subnets and with different gateways, but the same physical ethernet interface), using address A for all local traffic originating from the server, and address B for other machines behind the nat. I've done plenty of simple nat setups before but rarely worked with multiple non-localnet-only addresses on the same machine. Assuming the setup I want is possible, how do I go about setting it up?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from your requirement, you need to have two nat , one for the local network and another for the server itself. You want local ips/ LAN should go out via address A and Server generated traffic should go via address B.

**First Add address A and address B on external ethernet via sub interface.**

```
ifconfig eth0 address A/x.x.x.x

ifconfig eth0:1 address B/x.x.x.x
```

**Second Add the SNAT rule for LAN network**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s < LAN IP NETWORK > -o eth0 -j SNAT --to < address a >
```

**Third Add the SNAT for the rest (this will include the souce machine also)**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o eth0 -j SNAT --to < address B >
```

if this does not work, we can test.

Comment: Unfortunatel, this won't work (very well, if at all), as it ignores the routing issues.  If the [lowest metric] gateway is route A, all traffic which is not through a known route will exit via route A, regardless of source address.  Thus outgoing traffic will (pretty much) all go out 1 interface, and depending on if the providers do EGRESS filtering may or may not come back through one of the routers.

Comment: I was going to respond with a full howto, but its quite long.  have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/165182/policy-based-routing and http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have one primary interface `A` called `eth0`:

```
inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

and another interface `B` called `eth1`:

```
inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

Also there's third network `C` in subnet `10.0.0.0/24` from which we want to route traffic to either `A` or `B`.

First of all check `ip rule ls`:

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and main routing policy `ip route list table main`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev lxc  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 100
```

Now we want to add a rule for a mailserver with IP address `10.0.0.13` to route via `B` interface.

```
echo "200 mail" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.0.0.13 table mail
```

check routing table `ip rule ls`

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32765:  from 10.0.0.13 lookup mail 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Finally we add the default route and flush cache:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 table mail
ip route flush cache
```